# Using PHP to change rtf document and download msword file

Tags: php, rtf

```
<?php
    $pname = $_POST['pname'];
    $countyres = $_POST['countyres'];
    $a1name = $_POST['a1name'];
    $a2name = $_POST['a2name'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $county = $_POST['county'];
    $ha1name = $_POST['ha1name'];
    $ha2name = $_POST['ha2name'];
    $atty = $_POST['atty'];

    $FileContent = file_get_contents('xyzs.rtf');
    $FileContent = str_replace('%pname%', $pname, $FileContent);
    $FileContent = str_replace('%countyres%', $countyres, $FileContent);
    $FileContent = str_replace('%A1name%', $a1name, $FileContent);
    $FileContent = str_replace('%A2name%', $a2name, $FileContent);
    $FileContent = str_replace('%pmonth%', $month, $FileContent);
    $FileContent = str_replace('%day%', $day, $FileContent);
    $FileContent = str_replace('%year%', $year, $FileContent);
    $FileContent = str_replace('%county%', $county, $FileContent); 
    $FileContent = str_replace('%HA1name%', $ha1name, $FileContent);
    $FileContent = str_replace('%HA2name%', $ha2name, $FileContent);
    $FileContent = str_replace('%atty%', $atty, $FileContent);
    $fn = $pname.".doc";
file_put_contents($fn, $FileContent);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fn.'"');
header('Content-type: application/msword');
echo $fn;
exit();
?>
```

I have an html form that I post the above variables.  I am looking to load and rtf template file, conduct a search and replace on the variables inside the document.

There are two issues:
1. When I review the Response in Chrome tools, It gives me only the filename with the extension appended.

`2. I am not prompted to download the file.

Thank you.

Comment: You realise that you're not actually creating a msword file from an rtf template? Just pretending to do so

Comment: You might want to take a look at this https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: The problem turned out to be that my submit to the PHP file was not a form post, but a post using AJAX and JQuery.  When I placed to in elements in a Form directly to the PHP file, no problem.  Anyone know why?